# How to align multiple descriptions in mat-panel

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I'm trying to make the descriptions look more aligned in my mat-panel. If one field is longer than the other, it pushes everything to the right. How can I make the descriptions stay all aligned with each other?

```html
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="allExpandState">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Account #: {{accountNumber}}
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        {{type}}
      </mat-panel-description>
      <mat-panel-description>
        {{date}}
      </mat-panel-description>
      <mat-panel-description>
        {{value}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <!-- ... -->
</mat-accordion>
```

How it looks now:

[image: Broken expansion panels]

Comment: You could create just one mat-panel-description and create a table inside to align your values.

Comment: @Ploppy thanks! that worked

Answer (score 0):

You could create just one mat-panel-description and create a table inside to align your values.

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="allExpandState">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Account #: {{accountNumber}}
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <!-- ... -->
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark Ploppy's answer as Answered, if accepted. Another way of achieving alignment is:

Add a CSS rule to your component or in styles.css /scss

Note that ng-deep can be deprecated in the future.

```
    ::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
<mat-accordion>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let r of data">
        <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <mat-panel-title>
                    {{ r.title }})
                </mat-panel-title>
                <mat-panel-description>
                    {{ r.info }}
                    <mat-slide-toggle>Toggle</mat-slide-toggle>
                </mat-panel-description>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <h1>Details</h1>
            <p>...</p>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </ng-container>
</mat-accordion>
```

and

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your css file:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header-title,
.mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.mat-expansion-panel-header-description {
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header-title, .mat-expansion-panel-header-description {width: 25%;}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**